# convert an encoding to just alphabetical expression

Tags: python, encoding

I have a city name string such as

```
a='A Coruña'
```

How can I convert this into 'A Coruna'?

Best

Comment: The Unidecode package might do what you want: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode/

Comment: I'm curious why you want to do this. Are you working with some ancient ASCII-only system? Even if you can't use full Unicode, surely you can use an encoding like [Latin1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) that can handle simple accented letters.

Comment: I have two tables of city names that I need to match - one with 'A Coruña' and the other with 'A Coruna'.

Answer (score 2):

[The Unidecode module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode/) looks like it should do what you want.

Install it with:

```
pip install Unidecode
```

**Python 3**

In Python 3 it's pretty simple:

```
>>> from unidecode import unidecode
>>> a='A Coruña'
>>> unidecode(a)
'A Coruna'
```

**Python 2**

With Python 2, you'll need to either define your string as a Unicode string from the beginning:

```
a = u'A Coruña'
```

Or, if you've already got it as a string, you'll need to convert it to a Unicode string using `.decode()`:

```
a = 'A Coruña'.decode('utf-8')
```

And then you can run `unidecode(a)` as in the example for Python 3.

Comment: I'm getting UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 6: ordinal not in range(128). Would you know why by any chance? I have Python 2.7

Comment: Yup, I got the same error when testing on Python 2.7 - you'll need to make sure your string is defined as a Unicode string first. Will edit answer.

Answer (score 2):

for python 3.x

```
>>>import unicodedata
>>>a = 'A Coruña'
>>>search_string = ''.join((c for c in unicodedata.normalize('NFD', a)if unicodedata.category(c) != 'Mn'))
>>>print(search_string)
>>>A Coruna
```